# Convert swift arrays into JSON object

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have two arrays :

```
let value = [41, 42, 45] ...
let date = [NSDate1, NSDate2, NSDate3] ...
```

I need to save the data as a json object onto our mongodb on the server. I tested with a sample object formatted as below and it worked as expected.  How can I reformat my arrays into this format efficiently in swift/objective c?

```
let jsonObject = [
["date" : "2014/01/01", "value" : "41"],
["date" : "2014/01/02", "value" : "42"],
["date" : "2014/01/03", "value" : "45"]]
```

Any help would be very much appreciated ! Thank you !

Comment: NSJSONSerialization maybe? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html

Comment: I don't think it says anywhere there how to combine two arrays into a json object.

Comment: create a NSDictionary with both arrays and then convert it into a JSON with NSJSONSerialization

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking if that was possible, let me try to combine two arrays into a dictionary.  I can find out, but if you have an efficient way of doing it, it would be very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can zip the arrays and then map them into a dictionary.

You can run this code in a playground as an example.

```
let value = [41, 42, 45]
let date = [NSDate(), NSDate(), NSDate()]

let zippedArray = Array(zip(value, date))

let jsonObject = zippedArray.map({ (tuple: (value: Int, date: NSDate)) in
    return [
         "value"  :     String(tuple.value),
         "date"   :     String(_cocoaString: tuple.date) // You would probably want to use a method here that gives you the string in the format you want
    ]
})
```

Comment: That crashed the app !
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17001aa10'

Comment: You might need a convenience method on NSDate to convert the dates to the string format you want instead of using the String function.

Comment: Yeah, it works if I make the date a string of some sort!  How can I make the NSDate() into a String? format that does not crash the app?

Comment: Here is the output from mongodb when I sat the date = ["n1", "n2", "n3"]    > HealthData.findOne()
{ _id: '6k5j8BYaQQxAzWPFr',
  object: 
   [ { date: 'n1', value: '41' },
     { date: 'n2', value: '42' },
     { date: 'n3', value: '45' } ] }
> 
>

Comment: You should look up information about NSDateFormatters and make an extension on NSDate that gives you the format you want. But that's a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
let value = [41, 42, 45]
let date = [NSDate(), NSDate(), NSDate()]

let jsonArray = NSMutableArray()

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY/MM/dd"

for i in 0..<value.count {

    var jsonObject = Dictionary<String, String>()

    let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date[i])

    jsonObject["date"] = dateString
    jsonObject["value"] = value[i].description

    jsonArray.addObject(jsonObject)

}

println(jsonArray)

var error: NSError? = nil;
let jsonData: NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonArray, options: nil, error: &error)!
```

hope this helped.

Comment: Crashed the app:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteData)'

Comment: This is the output from the console, the first thing I notice is the semicolons.. and then equal signs, it should be colon between key and value

(
        {
        date = "2015/08/01";
        value = 41;
    },
        {
        date = "2015/08/01";
        value = 42;
    },
        {
        date = "2015/08/01";
        value = 45;
    }
)

Comment: Are you using the jsonData? @karlml

Answer (score 0):

I combined both's approach, and it worked.  Thank you :-)  Now I can go to bed.... 00:33am Thank you so much

```
func zipArrays()-> NSArray{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY/MM/dd"
    let zippedArray = Array(zip(value, date))

    let jsonObject = zippedArray.map({ (tuple: (value: Int, date: NSDate)) in
        return [
            "date"   :     String(_cocoaString: dateFormatter.stringFromDate(tuple.date) ),
            "value"  :     String(tuple.value)
        ]
    })

    return jsonObject
}
```

Comment: Output from meteor(mongodb) shell:

$ HealthData.findOne()


{ _id: 'LuYT27BsdGLuWNShf',
  object: 
   [ { date: '2015/08/01', value: '41' },
     { date: '2015/08/01', value: '42' },
     { date: '2015/08/01', value: '43' } ] }